# Is there a better way of achieving horizontal scrolling text effect imitating a limited character display?

Tags: string, loops, go, command-line-interface, slice

I'm trying to imitate a 16-character display on the command line which loops over a long string infinitely similar to a stock exchange ticker.

Right now, I'm first printing the first 16 byte slice of the ASCII string and moving over 1 byte at a time:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const (
    chars = 16
    text  = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available!!!"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("\033[2J") // clear screen
    buf := []byte(text)

    i := chars
    for {
        fmt.Print("\033[H") // move cursor back to first position
        fmt.Printf(string(buf[i-chars : i]))
        i++

        if i == len(buf)+1 {
            i = chars
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second / 4)

        // visualization of what's happening:
        // fmt.Printf("\t\t Character:%d of Length:%d | Slice: %d:%d \n", i, len(buf), i-chars, i)
    }
}
```

When I reach the end of the text, I reset the counter inside loop and start printing again from the first slice. Instead of doing this, I want to get to a "roll over" effect where the head of the slice seamlessly connects to the tail of the slice.

The problem is, I cannot use an empty buffer and append the head to the tail within the loop because it will just grow endlessly.

So instead of doing that, I decided to append the first 16 bytes of the string to it's tail before the loop and shrink the slice -16 bytes right away. But since that -16 bytes still exist in the backing array, I can expand/shrink from the loop:

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Print("\033[2J") // clear screen
    buf := []byte(text)
    buf = append(buf, buf[:chars]...)
    buf = buf[:len(buf)-chars]

    var expanded bool
    i := chars
    for {
        fmt.Print("\033[H") // move cursor back to first position
        fmt.Printf(string(buf[i-chars : i]))
        i++

        if i+1 == len(buf)-chars && !expanded {
            buf = buf[:len(buf)+chars]
            expanded = true
        }

        if i+1 == len(buf) {
            i = chars
            buf = buf[:len(buf)-chars]
            expanded = false
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)

        // visualization of what's happening:
        //fmt.Printf("\t\t Character:%d of Length:%d | Slice: %d:%d | Cap: %d\n", i, len(buf), i-chars, i, cap(buf))
    }
}
```

This gets me to where I want, but I'm rather new to Go so I want to know if there's a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would not change the buffer. It's a good idea to append the first 16 chars to the end of it to easily get the "rolling over" effect, but it's much easier and cheaper to just reset the position to `0` when you reach its end.

Next, you don't need to operate on a byte slice. Just operate on a `string`. Strings can be indexed and sliced, just like slices, and slicing a `string` doesn't even make a copy (doesn't have to), it returns a new string (header) which shares the backing array of the string data. Don't forget that indexing and slicing `string`s uses byte index (not `rune` index) which is fine for ASCII texts (their characters are mapped to bytes one-to-one in UTF-8), but would not work with multi-byte special characters.  Your example text is fine.

Also don't use [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) to print a text, that expects a format `string` (treats its first argument as a format string). Instead just use [`fmt.Print()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print).

All in all, your solution can be reduced to this which is much-much better performance-wise, and it's much cleaner and simpler:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Print("\033[2J") // clear screen
    s := text + text[:chars]

    for i := 0; ; i = (i + 1) % len(text) {
        fmt.Print("\033[H") // move cursor back to first position
        fmt.Print(s[i : i+chars])
        time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
    }
}
```

Also note that when position reaches `len(text)`, we reset it to `0`, so the text before that starts with the last char of `text` and uses `chars-1` from the beginning. So it's also enough to append `chars-1` instead of `chars`:

```
s := text + text[:chars-1]
```